# Shelf life of canned and unfermented wort?

Tags: wort, yeast-starters, shelf-life

I asked in a [prior post about canning wort](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11507/canning-unfermented-wort-for-yeast-farming) to have it handy for yeast farming. What would the shelf life be of canned, unfermented wort? Any special steps to extend shelf life, perhaps adding hops?

What I'm getting at, is would it be possible to do a huge batch (several gallons) and keep it for a year or two? On the surface it sounds like it would be plausible, as the contents are sterilized in the canning process and many things have a shelf life this long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you pressure can it, you should be able to do what you propose.